# Split data frame list

Tags: list, dataframe, split

I'm just starting out on R and couldn't find any info on this...

I have created a for loop to fetch data from multiple `.csv` files which creates a list of data frames in Rstudio. As far as I am aware, `ggplot` doesn't like lists and I therefore want to split the list into individual data frames so that I can use it.

I have done it for an individual data frame as follows:

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(file.list[1])
```

Is there a way of doing this for each data frame in the list without going through it manually? I will also be looking to use the same `ggplot` functions on each data frame which is why I thought the list was a good idea...